# Cannot play/stop ringingtone using a slider button

Tags: flutter

Im trying to play a ringintone when the class is initialized and turn in off using a slider buttion.Player is created successfully upon initialization,but for some reason cannot turn it off using the slider button due to following error.

E/flutter ( 6529): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method hasVibrator on channel vibration)
E/flutter ( 6529): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter ( 6529): 
E/flutter ( 6529): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 6529): #2      Vibration.hasVibrator (package:slider_button/src/vibration.dart:20:43)

But I have not used the Vibrator in any way.Folloing is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:slider_button/slider_button.dart';
import 'package:correcteddistancetrack/Interfaces/ringingtone.dart';


class snoozeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _snoozeScreenState createState() => _snoozeScreenState();
}

class _snoozeScreenState extends State<snoozeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState(){

    RingPhone().ringnow();
    

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //color: Colors.red,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [Colors.blueAccent,Colors.greenAccent]
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SliderButton(
              label: Text("Slide to stop alarm",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
              icon: Icon(Icons.alarm,size: 40,),
              action: (){
                RingPhone().stopNow();
                
                //Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              width: 320,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Really grateful if anyone can assist

Comment: Issue recovered after a flutter clean.No idea on the root cause though

Answer (score 0):

By default it was true, you make `vibrationFlag: false`, it should work